# convert into hh:mm:ss from days in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I'm trying to convert days into hh:mm:ss

Can anyone help me to solve this problem using mathematics logic ?

I was following following example, which is used to convert seconds into hh:mm:ss

```
round(floor((Time_Sec/3600)),0) + ":" + round(floor((mod(Time_Sec, 3600))/60),0) + ":" + round(floor(mod(mod(Time_Sec, 3600),60)),0)
```

Not suceeeded ....
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Too many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: @jarlh, mysql am using

Comment: Calculate how many seconds are in a day, multiply it with the number of days you have and you can use the above formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from days to seconds easily enough, then you can use [`SEC_TO_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to do the remaining conversion for you.